# Keeping line in file that do not match with list of words in another file

Tags: awk, sed

I want to keep lines in a file that do not match with a list of words kept in another file (not the whole line match). For a toy dataset, I have created a list_file.txt which contains:

```
BGC0001184
BGC0000853
```

And a large_file.txt that contains:

```
contig com1_25_species_1.25M_idxstats.txt
BGC0000853 0
BGC0000853 14
BGC0000853 2
BGC0000854 6
BGC0001185 7
BGC0001185 13
BGC0001184 31
BGC0001186 11
BGC0001184 31
BGC0001184 31
```

And I use grep as follows:

```
grep -vf list_file.txt large_file.txt
```

All good. I get the desired output:

```
contig com1_25_species_1.25M_idxstats.txt
BGC0000854 6
BGC0001185 7
BGC0001185 13
BGC0001186 11
```

Now, when I try to apply the same on real large dataset (same format, large files), it’s not working.
What am I missing here? Please let me know if you have any awk/sed suggestions.
Thanks.

Link for my large dataset files are below:

List File:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14wa6iopzgZUz56C8a3eWRvLPyU_PkCMK/view?usp=sharing

Large File:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O3LYE15o9wJmMmsdxcb4xzjaIw1E9VYa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Both file links are denying access

Comment: Ah my bad, I have given permission now.. sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your shown samples, could you please try following, written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '{sub(/\r$/,"")} FNR==NR{arr[$0];next} !($1 in arr)' list_file.txt contig
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case your values are NOT exact same(1st fields of list and contig files) and you want to do partial matching then try following.

```
awk '{sub(/\r$/,"")} FNR==NR{arr[$0];next} {for(i in arr){if(index($0,i)){next}}} 1' list_file.txt contig
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But the same issue with grep is showing in the output for the large files.

Comment: @Bob, ok so you are saying its not working? OR its giving an error? Kindly do let me know on same, thank you.

Comment: its not working. I should have got 415 lines in (large data) output file, not the 653 which I am getting

Comment: @Bob, ok with your shown samples it worked. Giving links/images for samples is not recommended, could you please do update your post with samples(few lines only) which are very similar to your actual file, let me know on same, thank you.

Comment: actually that's the issue. The toy example file (what I shown) is the exact smaller version of the main files. The grep code and your suggested awk code works on that, but I am not getting the output in my original data files.

Comment: @Bob, so you want the output to be saved into `contig` itself? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: No, I want to make a new output file.

Comment: @Bob, could you please give some lines which are not coming in output?

Comment: If you open the Large File link, it has 563 lines. I have a list file (with 157 line of words). Some of the words in the list file are matched with lines of large file. I want to print rest of the lines in large files (that do not match) in a separate output file. I manually checked that I should have got 415 lines in my final output file. But I am getting  563 lines with above codes. Thanks for your help, please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @Bob, sorry it's blocked in my office laptop, but when I checked on mobile looks like your samples are of same shown kind, could you please run `cat -v file` on your both of the files once? Let me know if you see any control M characters there? Thank you

Comment: @Bob, cool, please try my edited solution once and let me know if those helps you now? cheers.

Comment: I will.. trying this now

Comment: @Bob, OR change `{sub(/\r$/,"")}` to `{gsub(/\r/,"")}` in case you want to remove all control M characters, current sub will remove only last control M but gsub will remove all(which I think you don't need them :) ). Try both please.